# multicolumn command with tabularx environment

Tags: tables, tabularx

I am using the multicolumn command within tabularx and am not getting any joy. I want to organise it so that the top line spans across two separate columns and wraps itself appropriately, but I cant get it working.

```
\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
{\small
\hfill{}  \centering
  \caption{Add caption}
    \begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{*{12}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}}
    \toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{X}{} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{Experimental Frequency (Hz) \citep{Saiidi1994}} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\cite{Kim2004} Analytical Model Predicted Frequency (Hz)} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{} & \multicolumn{2}{X}{\cite{Kim2004} FE Model Predicted Frequency (Hz)} &\multicolumn{2}{X}{} \\
    \cline{3-12}
    Case  & In-situ prestress force (kN) & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1 (\% diff) & Mode 2 (\% diff) & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1 (\% diff) & Mode 2 (\% diff) \\
    \midrule
    1     & 0.00  & 11.41 & 43.99 & 11.41 & 45.64 & 0.0\% & -3.7\% & 11.20 & 44.05 & 1.9\% & -0.1\% \\
    2     & 15.71 & 12.09 & 44.11 & 11.83 & 46.06 & 2.1\% & -4.4\% & 11.69 & 44.55 & 3.3\% & -1.0\% \\
    3     & 27.05 & 13.47 & 44.89 & 12.13 & 46.37 & 10.0\% & -3.3\% & 12.03 & 44.89 & 10.7\% & 0.0\% \\
    4     & 36.49 & 12.89 & 44.69 & 12.37 & 46.63 & 4.0\% & -4.3\% & 12.31 & 45.16 & 4.5\% & -1.1\% \\
    5     & 57.25 & 13.63 & 45.62 & 12.89 & 47.18 & 5.5\% & -3.4\% & 12.90 & 45.74 & 5.3\% & -0.3\% \\
    6     & 81.81 & 14.49 & 45.57 & 13.47 & 47.83 & 7.1\% & -5.0\% & 13.57 & 46.40 & 6.4\% & -1.8\% \\
    7     & 91.26 & 14.72 & 46.32 & 13.69 & 48.07 & 7.0\% & -3.8\% & 13.82 & 46.65 & 6.1\% & -0.7\% \\
    8     & 121.46 & 14.72 & 45.86 & 14.36 & 48.85 & 2.4\% & -6.5\% & 14.58 & 47.40 & 1.0\% & -3.4\% \\
    9     & 130.91 & 14.97 & 46.10 & 14.57 & 49.10 & 2.7\% & -6.5\% & 14.81 & 47.62 & 1.1\% & -3.3\% \\
    10    & 132.80 & 15.07 & 45.87 & 14.61 & 49.15 & 3.1\% & -7.1\% & 14.86 & 47.67 & 1.4\% & -3.9\% \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}%
  \label{tab:addlabel}
  }
\end{table}%
```

Comment: sorry i wasnt allowed to post the output picture

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think `tabularx` is gaining you anything here, most of the table data is numeric so can't line wrapped to different lengths. I think I'd do something more like this, perhaps some more refinements but...

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs}
\def\citep#1{#1}
\begin{document}

\def\tabularxcolumn#1{m{#1}}

\begin{table}[htbp]
\small \setlength\tabcolsep{2pt}
\centering
  \caption{Add caption}

    \hspace*{-1cm}\begin{tabular}{*{12}{r}}
    \toprule
    Case &
    \multicolumn{1}{p{1.5cm}}{\centering In-situ prestress force (kN)}& 
\multicolumn{2}{p{3cm}}{\centering Experimental Frequency (Hz) \citep{Saiidi1994}} &
 \multicolumn{4}{p{5cm}}{\centering \cite{Kim2004} Analytical Model Predicted Frequency (Hz)} & 
\multicolumn{4}{p{5cm}}{\cite{Kim2004} FE Model Predicted Frequency (Hz)}  \\
    \cline{3-12}
 &  & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1  & Mode 2  & Mode 1 & Mode 2 & Mode 1  & Mode 2 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  (\% diff) &(\% diff) &  &  &  (\% diff) & (\% diff) \\
    \midrule
    1     & 0.00  & 11.41 & 43.99 & 11.41 & 45.64 & 0.0\% & -3.7\% & 11.20 & 44.05 & 1.9\% & -0.1\% \\
    2     & 15.71 & 12.09 & 44.11 & 11.83 & 46.06 & 2.1\% & -4.4\% & 11.69 & 44.55 & 3.3\% & -1.0\% \\
    3     & 27.05 & 13.47 & 44.89 & 12.13 & 46.37 & 10.0\% & -3.3\% & 12.03 & 44.89 & 10.7\% & 0.0\% \\
    4     & 36.49 & 12.89 & 44.69 & 12.37 & 46.63 & 4.0\% & -4.3\% & 12.31 & 45.16 & 4.5\% & -1.1\% \\
    5     & 57.25 & 13.63 & 45.62 & 12.89 & 47.18 & 5.5\% & -3.4\% & 12.90 & 45.74 & 5.3\% & -0.3\% \\
    6     & 81.81 & 14.49 & 45.57 & 13.47 & 47.83 & 7.1\% & -5.0\% & 13.57 & 46.40 & 6.4\% & -1.8\% \\
    7     & 91.26 & 14.72 & 46.32 & 13.69 & 48.07 & 7.0\% & -3.8\% & 13.82 & 46.65 & 6.1\% & -0.7\% \\
    8     & 121.46 & 14.72 & 45.86 & 14.36 & 48.85 & 2.4\% & -6.5\% & 14.58 & 47.40 & 1.0\% & -3.4\% \\
    9     & 130.91 & 14.97 & 46.10 & 14.57 & 49.10 & 2.7\% & -6.5\% & 14.81 & 47.62 & 1.1\% & -3.3\% \\
    10    & 132.80 & 15.07 & 45.87 & 14.61 & 49.15 & 3.1\% & -7.1\% & 14.86 & 47.67 & 1.4\% & -3.9\% \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}\hspace*{-1cm}
  \label{tab:addlabel}

\end{table}%

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you David, your feedback is much appreciated!!, But is the solution simply to manually edit the column widths?

Comment: @nobleda it's possible to make it a bit more automatic and if you were printing database output with thousands of tables a week you would want that, but if it was my data and my table, I'd do it by hand and not use tabularx (even if I wrote that package:-)